# How to get accurate fragment screen position, like gl_FragCood in vertex shader?

Tags: opengl, unity-game-engine, glsl, shader, vertex-shader

I did some calculations using projected gl_Position and screen parameters, but position seems distorted in polygons close to the camera. But when I use...

```
vec2 fragmentScreenCoordinates = vec2(gl_FragCoord.x / _ScreenParams.x, gl_FragCoord.y / _ScreenParams.y);
```

...I got pretty accurate `xy` results.

Pretty output gl_FragCoord.xy coordinates:
[image]

Calculating from projected vertices results in interpolated values all over the faces, which I cannot use for sampling screen aligned textures.

Ugly interpolated output from gl_Position:
[image]

Is there a way to produce this `gl_FragCoord`-like value in vertex shader? I really want to calculate texture coordinates in vertex shader for independent texture reads, manual depth tests, etc.

Or is there any Unity built in values I can use here?

Comment: Are you using a perspective projection? If you do, you'll have to include the perspective division, which means dividing by `gl_FragCoord.w`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the vertex shader, you set

```
gl_Position = ...
```

This must be in clip space, before the perspective divide to normalized device coordinates. This is because OpenGL does a bunch of stuff in the 4D space and is necessary for interpolation.

Since you just want the value *at* each vertex and nothing interpolated, you can normalize right away (or can even [leave out if using an orthographic projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26967339/under-which-conditions-can-i-leave-out-the-perspective-division))...

```
vec3 ndc = gl_Position.xyz / gl_Position.w; //perspective divide/normalize
vec2 viewportCoord = ndc.xy * 0.5 + 0.5; //ndc is -1 to 1 in GL. scale for 0 to 1
vec2 viewportPixelCoord = viewportCoord * viewportSize;
```

Here, **`viewportCoord`** is the equivalent of your `fragmentScreenCoordinates`, assuming the viewport covers the window.

**Note:** as @derhass points out, this will fail if geometry intersects the `w = 0` plane. I.e. a visible triangle's vertex is behind the camera.

[*EDIT*]
The comments discuss using the coordinates for 1 to 1 pixel nearest neighbor lookup. As @AndonM.Coleman says, changing the coordinates will work, but it's easier and faster to use nearest neighbor filtering. You can also use `texelFetch`, which bypasses filtering altogether:

1. Snap the coordinates:

   ```
   vec2 sampleCoord = (floor(viewportPixelCoord) + 0.5) / textureSize(mySampler);
   vec4 colour = texture(mySampler, sampleCoord);
   ```
2. Nearest neighbor filtering (not sure what this is in unity3d):

   ```
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); //magnification is the important one here
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
   ```
3. Use `texelFetch`:

   ```
   vec4 colour = texelFetch(mySampler, ivec2(viewportPixelCoord), 0);
   ```

Comment: If I'm right, these `xy` coordinates are not aligned to device pixels perfectly, I mean these `xy` coordinates are "inter-pixel" values somehow. Having this, they are not quiet suitable to sample from a viewport aligned texture (like a depth map). The actual texture sample may vary depending on geometry. Does it make sense to "snap" these values to actual pixels here? Something like round to the nearest pixel position.

Comment: @Geri: That's how rasterization works, so it's perfectly fine. The fragments are all sampled at pixel center by convention. I should point out that you don't want rounding though. What you want to do is snap to the nearest pixel center. You can achieve this simply by implicitly converting from floating-point to integer in GLSL, rather than rounding that will give you the `floor` and that's the exact behavior you need to snap to **0.5**. If you use the `viewportCoord` values for a texture lookup, you actually don't have to worry about any of this though if you use nearest-neighbor filtering.

Comment: Hey, using nearest-neighbor sounds really awesome, thanks! Only if I can set it to a system exported camera depth texture. It is managed somehow internal in Unity. Hope it works, I could also spare performance there.

Comment: It was not the pixel misalignment, the distorsion is way too notable.

Comment: It comes from the linear interpolation between vertex screen `xy` samples, so derive values from gl_Position can't be the solution (see pictures in updated question).

Comment: @Now with your update I'm really confused. If you want per-pixel shading you have to use per-pixel shading otherwise you use per-vertex shading and get linearly interpolated colour. There's no way around that. Trying to interpolate `ndc` after the perspective divide will break, because OpenGl will give you a [perspective correct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_mapping#Perspective_correctness) interpolation. You could use `noperspective` but then why not just use `gl_FragCoord`?

Comment: Wow, thanks, it is seemingly the perspective correct interpolation. Gonna look after `noperspective`. I'm doing this actually: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/reuse-depth-buffer-of-main-camera.280460/ you may understand the whole picture better.

Comment: I want to see independent texture read performance payout, where I can calculate UVs in vertex shader. Suggested all over the place when targeting mobile https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/BestPracticesforShaders/BestPracticesforShaders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH7-SW15.

Comment: @Geri but `gl_FragCoord` already has what you want. OpenGL computes it anyway as part of the rasterization process. Computing texture coordinates you already have implicitly seems to be just extra overhead.

Comment: Yap, I know. Just people say: "Don't calculate UVs in the fragment shader, if you want optimized texture reads." (see Apple link above). Thatswhy I wanted to put this up to vertex shader.

Comment: There is a general issue with the solution suggested in this answer: it will not work in the general case. It is just not possible to get meaningful NDC coordinates without taking the clipping into account (which needs to see the full primitive, hence is impossible to do in a vertex shader). The issue will show up when one has a perspective projection and primitives intersecting the near plane, especially if at least on point of the primitive lies in front of, and at least one other point lies behind the camera.

Comment: @derhass that's a very good point. I'll add a note. I could be wrong but I don't think the near plane is the issue, it'd be `w = 0` that causes problems. Not far off though.

Comment: @jozxyqk: You are right in that the near plane isn't really special. But it is not just `w=0`. It is also everything behind the camera (mirroring the projected point in front of the camera). With the usual GL conventions, that means `w <= 0` will result in problems. These problems will only show up if the primitive is at least partly visible, so at least one point of it must lie behind the near plane. That's why I wrote "intersecting the near plane", although that is only necessary, but not sufficient to trigger the issue.